# Power consumption PDU

Tags: electrical-power, ups, apc

As you can see in the image below, I can't get the consumption.
Even if I send the log via FTP there's no info about the consumption.

[image: PDU interface]

I already checked on APC PDU website and co and i didn't found any info.

```
Model Number: AP7821 

Application Module 
Version: v3.7.0 
Date: 01/13/2009 


APC OS (AOS) 
Version: v3.7.0 
Date: 01/13/2009
```

---

**Update**

This is an exemple of another PDU i have. In red you can see the Kwh consumption. This is what i need.

[image]

Comment: Its the PDU, but the UPS say what ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 the UPS gives the total consumption. But i don't want to calculate every month (total - consumption = this PDU). I swear if that's a problem with the OS version.

Comment: what consumption are you expecting to get? kWh? I'm a bit confused exactly what your trying to do here if you could clarify.

Comment: @user3788685 i've updated the OP

Comment: Ok thanks - I notice that 'other' PDU has an 'environmental' tab, but yours does not. Are you missing some functions, modules or this this a different model pdu or firmware?

Answer (score 1):

After a short discussion with APC company, the model AP7821 doesn't show the consumption in KwH but in amper even in the last firmware update.

Comment: Well, they're pretty closely related!